# Check that a ressource is shared by different proccess

Tags: c, file, process, kernel, system-calls

I've written the following code in order to check if two proccess, let's call them pid1 and pid2 share the same process with their respective file descriptors.

1) I open a file in my first process.
2) Store the file descriptor.
3) Fork
4) Open the same file in the child process
5) Use kcmp to check

```
fd1 = open("test", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0600);
pid1 = getpid();
pid2 = fork();

if (!pid2) {
    pid2 = getpid();
    fd2 = open("test", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
    i = kcmp(pid1, pid2, 0, fd1, fd2);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
else
{
    int status;
    int s;
    while ((s = wait(&status)) > 0);
}
```

To check this, I use the syscall kcmp with the flag  KCMP_FILE (equivalent to 0). However the syscall always returns 1 or 2 instead of 0.

The expected result is 0 because the two proccess share the same resource with their file descriptors.

Did I misunderstand the man page or I am doing something wrong to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did I misunderstand the man page or I am doing something wrong to check this?

You misunderstood the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kcmp.2.html), which says this:

> ```
> KCMP_FILE
>           Check whether a file descriptor idx1 in the process pid1
>           refers to the same open file description (see open(2)) as file
>           descriptor idx2 in the process pid2.
> ```

The specific wording is deliberate and very important: for `KCMP_FILE`, `kcmp()` determines whether to FDs refer to the same *open file **description***, which is a very different thing from refering to the same underlying file.  Following the reference to `open(2)`, we find:

> A call to `open()` creates a new *open file description*, an entry in the
>   system-wide table of open files.

(Emphasis added.)  You have two calls to `open()`.  Each creates its own new open file description.  These are not the same, even though they refer to the same file, and `kcmp()` tells you so.  The only way I know to get two distinct FDs in the same process that refer to the same open file description is via the `dup()` family of functions.